# Inserting a row into a Pandas Dataframe in a certain column (without a name)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
            value1 value2 value3
2021-04-26  22       22    22   
2021-04-27  21       26    26 
2021-04-28  27       29    27
```

However, after inserting a new row like:

```
row: {'value1': 40, 'value2': 40, 'value3': 40}
df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

The date column (even though it doesn't have a label) gets transformed into:

```
   value1 value2 value3
0  22       22    22   
1  21       26    26 
2  27       29    27 
3  40       40    40
```

Instead of: (desired output)

```
            value1 value2 value3
2021-04-26  22       22    22   
2021-04-27  21       26    26 
2021-04-28  27       29    27 
NaN         40       40    40
```

How can I add a new row with a certain date but without changing the whole dataframe, so I would get my desired output? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are not strictly inclined having index as NaN and the dict can be a list of dicts, you may try `df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row,orient='index').T)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append it as a DataFrame with `np.nan` as its index:

```
row = {'value1': 40, 'value2': 40, 'value3': 40}
df.append(pd.DataFrame([row], index=[np.nan]))
```

Output:

```
            value1  value2  value3
2021-04-26      22      22      22
2021-04-27      21      26      26
2021-04-28      27      29      27
NaN             40      40      40
```

Answer (score 1):

The date is an index. Reset index before appending:

```
df.reset_index()
```